# PHP command with docker volume is not working

Tags: php, symfony, docker, command

I put my Symfony project into Docker, using a volume for my code. I want to user a php command (`php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle:MyEntity` to be precise).

When I try to use my php command outside docker, where my code is, nothing happen. But when I connect myself into my docker, the php command is running well.

Do you know why my php command is not working outside my docker ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe because php is not installed?

Comment: @alex not cause of this, the php command I'm able to use it everywhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker contains your PHP image, it is only accessible from your container. If you try to make your order out of your Docker, it will not just find PHP sources because they are containerized

Your Symfony application can find them because you have indicated the way to the sources Dockers, that's all :)

Comment: Oh i see, so maybe i didn't well understood. The symfony file / code i wrote is just like a pointer to the file that are actually inside the docker ? I think it's in my computer environment, but in reality my code is inside the docker right ?